# New protected member declared in struct

Tags: c#

The C# compiler complains about the following code containing `new protected member declared in struct`. What is the problem?

```
struct Foo {
    protected Object _bar;
}
```

Comment: Well, you are correct that I jumped the gun, I thought that the error message continued beyond what you posted.  That said, just copy/pasting it into google leads to the [doc page for that error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd2e1t2c(v=vs.80).aspx), which states that all structs are sealed.  All of the other top search results resulted in equal or better quality solutions, so I'm not sure how you could have searched and found nothing.

Comment: @Servy I did come across that. It pointed me in the right direction, but it still didn't explain that C# won't let you declare protected member data in the sealed class (even though, to the best of my knowledge, this is functionally the same as 'private' and could therefore be implicitly treated as such), but rather requires you to declare your member data 'private' instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is a struct, it cannot be overridden. It seems the C# compiler wants sealed types like structs to use the 'private' keyword rather than the 'protected' keyword, even though functionally there isn't any difference. Use this instead:

```
struct Foo {
    private Object _bar;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd2e1t2c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
A struct cannot be abstract and is always implicitly sealed.
```

It looks like C# wants you to use "private" instead of protected.

Answer (score 2):

Structs are implicitly sealed so you can't create descendants any way and protected modifier means that only instance of this type and all instances of derived types has access to it.

Comment: In fact, this is the most precise explanation. MSDN is just a bit more verbose saying that "A struct cannot be abstract and is always implicitly sealed. Because structs do not support inheritance, the concept of a protected member in a struct makes no sense."

[see ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd2e1t2c(v=vs.90).aspx)